# How to upload custom image when create new channel

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

We need to have the ability to set a custom image for new channels.

From docs https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#initialize_channel, I can see the field `image` and if send here some remote URL - works fine.

But what to do when we need to send an image from the phone? For sending image for message I can see the functionality. But it's bonded to channel which is going to be created.

I know we can use base64, but I hope there is a better way of doing the required functionality? (like upload the image to server and get remoteURL)?

Comment: Did you check this for uploading/sending image and files - https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#file_uploads

Comment: sure! And as I mentioned in questions - this file/image uploads requires the channel object, which is not created yet. Or is it supposed to work like: create a channel(without image) -> upload image -> update channel with uploaded image?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question earlier. But yeah, for now this is the only possible way for you to attach local image on channel - create a channel(without image) -> upload image -> update channel with uploaded image. 

Allowing image/file uploads outside of channel context is currently on our roadmap. So in near future, it will be available mostly.

Comment: @vishtree so, I guess for user-avatar uploading is not implemented too? Since it's outside channel context. Is there some ETA?

Comment: Can you please raise a feature request on our github repo? https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/issues

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to do this. You may have to write some code that first uploads the image to a storage bucket at a cloud provider of your choice. Once that image is uploaded, you should be able to get the public url for that image. Once you have that public image url, you should be able to create the channel and pass the url.

I know that's not what you were asking, but this is the only workaround I can think of.